# Suggested ways to do a Google-Earth-like fly-to-the-location effect with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

What are the suggested ways to do a fly-to-the-location effect, similar to the one when opening Google Earth, with OpenLayers?  While it might be possible to draw this with OpenLayers API, we would like to know if there are better (smoother and slicker) ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you were to try and do this with current OpenLayers it would require a lot of fiddling with animations and tweens and all stuff I have never bothered with. However, it looks like the upcoming OpenLayers 3 will be able to do this sort of thing out of the box. Try it out by heading to the [OpenLayers 3 Animation Example](http://ol3js.org/ol3/master/examples/animation.html) page and hit the 'Fly to Bern' button.

OL3 is still in the Alpha stages of development though so this solution is not really one you can do now. Just thought it was worth mentioning!

Comment: Hmm... upgrading to OL3 seems too big a leap for us.  I was hoping there are some other solutions to this.

Comment: Oh yeah, I wouldn't upgrade, especially since it is still in Alpha. I was just thinking that if its feature you aren't too bothered about for now and could maybe implement it whenever OL3 is released, save writing something yourself to do it. I guess if you had the time you could dive into the OpenLayers 3 code and see how they do it? I haven't looked myself.